# Future of Azure cloud service

Tags: azure, cloud

Majority of our line of business application hosted on Azure Cloud service.

We would like to understand Microsoft's future strategy on Cloud Service and how long this platform will be supported.

We also understand from different forum that , Microsoft progressively started disabling various feature from Cloud Service.

Should we continue to use cloud service or switch to other PAS offering like App Service

Comment: More than likely this question will be closed as it is not really suitable for this place. Having said that, personally I find it very odd that Microsoft is completely silent on the future of Cloud Services. Given that Microsoft has not announced anything on that front, the Cloud Services will continue to work. General recommendation is that any new development shouldn't be done on Cloud Services. Rather other PaaS offerings from Microsoft (like Service Fabric, App Service etc.) should be used for new development.

Comment: This might guide you as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-compare. It also stated it is a legacy service and service fabric is the recommended replacement